# Do Reuters or Eikon have intraday exchange rate data for minor currencies?

Tags: fx, bloomberg, currency, intraday, reuters

I need historical intraday exchange rate data (for a minor european currency - EURRSD) for my thesis. Not necessarily tick by tick - just prices at any interval below an hour will work.

I guess there is no need to describe my situation here but because where I am geographically I am not able to check them myself, though I do have access to them.
It would be very useful to know if they have it or should I look for alternative sources (any ideas where, if needed?).

Thank you.